# XS Max Simulator on Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9, ios12, iphone-xs-max

I'm trying to place my apps on my XS Max, but since I only have Xcode 9 I can't get it to work on the arm64e architecture. I've tried to update the MacBook in order to get Xcode 10, but since this is a school MacBook, they restrict updating to High Sierra.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: what is the question ? you need xcode 10 for xs max simulator

Comment: @andesta.erfan just curious if there is any work arounds or ways to make the xs max work on xcode 9

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use an iPhone XS Max with Xcode 9 (nor a simulator, neither a physical device), since it runs iOS 12+, for which the debugging support is only available for Xcode 10 (and newer).

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Shame I can't get xcode 10 to run on sierra.